# c# - Auto incrementing AssemblyInformationalVersion

Tags: c#, version, .net-assembly

I would like to auto increment the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` so I can use `Application.ProductVersion` to obtain a product version for my program. I use `[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("4.1.*")]` to define it however `*` does not increment the number as it is supposed to (I get the `*` as it is in the product version string). What should I do ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [Build Version Increment](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It this case this link **IS** the answer. You cannot download that plugin from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I used this NuGet plugin in one of my project, it worked well:
[Auto Version Incrementer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e30465a4-dab9-44ca-815b-b390ceeef6ab?SRC=VSIDE)